# Reading from Azure DataLake & Writing to Google BigQuery via Databricks

Tags: azure, google-bigquery, azure-databricks

I am trying to read from Azure Datalake and write to Bigquery .
Refered
https://docs.databricks.com/external-data/bigquery.html

I have created 2 service accounts in GCP  and generated the json keys and has uploaded it in /tmp location in dbfs.. when executing the write to bigquery using the spark command it throws an exception that
**

com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:**
and the underlying error was FileNotFound
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: dbfs/tmp/gcpaccess.json (No such file or directory)
the json file is present in dbfs:/tmp and file :/tmp location in databricks

Comment: show the code that you're using

Answer (score 0):

By looking at error it seems like it is not able to get the Json file that contain key and other information.

- Upload your Json file under dbfs >> filestore.
- Now, copy file from dbfs to temporary file location.

```py
%fs cp "dbfs location" "temporary location"
```

(If you are using Azure Databricks no need to copy temporary location)

- Then use credential path as `/temp/filename`

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x2RoOe6PjUQ) by Azarudin shahul explain all the procedure to connect big query to databricks.